# nested for...in loop that lists properties(objects) of a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript

I can't wrap my head around how to nest for...in loops in each other to list out all the properties in a multi dimensional object.

```
var list = {};
list.one = {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true
};
list.two = {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true
};

var listing = function(obj) {
    for (prop in obj) {
        document.write(prop+"<br>");        
        for (props in obj) { //not sure what to write here
            document.write("---"+props+"<br>");
        }
}

listing(list);
```

How do I write the for loops to get something like this:

```
one
---true
---false
---true
two
---true
---false
---true
```

Does each successively nested for...in loop need to be more complex, testing whether the object is indeed multidimensional? I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to iterate over the inner object in your inner loop. See below:

```
var list = {};
list.one = {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true
};
list.two = {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true
};

var listing = function(outerObj) {
    for (var outerProp in outerObj) {
        var innerObj = outerObj[outerProp];

        document.write(prop+"<br>");

        for (var innerProp in innerObj) {
            document.write("---"+props+"<br>");
        }
}

listing(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate the inner object, `obj[prop]`:

```
function listing(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        document.write(prop+"<br>");        
        for (var nestedProp in obj[prop]) {
            document.write("---"+nestedProp+": "+obj[prop][nestedProp]+"<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

> Does each successively nested for...in loop need to be more complex, testing whether the object is indeed multidimensional?

No, if you know the number of dimensions beforehand you don't need to test for it and can just nest loops. For an arbitrary number of levels you'd use a recursive function which would need to test whether the argument is an enumerable object are a "leaf" value.